# Split text to multiple rows - an alternative to TEXTSPLIT

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Office 365

TEXTSPLIT: I do not have this new function.
Please suggest a solution.
I do not know VBA.

Problem: a download from our accounting service to an excel file places all data into one cell with no delimiters. Data would be about 200 rows.

Searching other post(s): there are ~1600 posts so didn't search all

- Split data from single cell into multiple records: there is some similarity to the post except there are no AltReturns within the cell to separate data.
- How can I split Excel data from one row into multiple rows: I am looking into Power Query, but the suggested response believes there are comma delimiters

Data example of 4 records in same cell:

```
APS Deposit 04/01/2022 $5,174.27 APS ACH Deposit 04/04/2022 $65,186.66 APS Deposit 04/04/2022 $10,380.00 APS Deposit 04/05/2022 $5,943.36
```

Desired result, with columns spaced out:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APS Deposit | 04/01/2022 | $5,174.27 |
| APS ACH Deposit | 04/04/2022 | $65,186.66 |
| APS Deposit | 04/04/2022 | $10,380.00 |
| APS Deposit | 04/05/2022 | $5,943.33 |

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use import these data into Power Query, then use Split Column > By Delimiter > Enter "APS" under Custom and choose split data into Rows.

[image]

Then click Remove Rows and choose Remove Blank Rows.

[image]

Click Custom Column > Enter the formula `Text.Combine({"APS",[Column1]})` to add "APS" back.

[image]

Remove the previous column and left the new column of "Custom". And continue to split the column.

Click Split Column > By Delimiter > Enter "$" under Custom, choose Columns and enter "2".

[image]

Select Custom.1 column > Split Column > By Number of Characters > Enter 11 and choose "Once, as far right as possible".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in Power Query:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Insert delimiters by prepending semicolon to every instance of " APS" (so will exclude the first "APS"
    #"Insert Delimiters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column1", each Text.Replace(_," APS",";APS")}),

//Split by the semicolon into rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Insert Delimiters", {
        {"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),

//Split the column by the last two spaces {" "," "}
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Column1", 
         Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "," "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Type", "Date","Amount"}),

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Date", type date}, {"Amount", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supose you have data pasted in A1 cell. 
You can use formula in any other other cell as shown below:

```
=CONCATENATE("APS " & FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1; "APS"; "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"; "//s"))
```

First cell in output will give you error - that's because input string starts with "APS" and filter gets substituted string starting with "</s><s>". You can try to workaround this issue further.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done easily with built-in functions in Excel, especially if you do not know VBA.

If you do not mind using other tools, I highly suggest to process raw data in Sublime Text.
It is like advanced version of Notepad, and my favorite feature of it is that it allows you to effortlessly select specific characters, and then edit them SIMULTANEOUSLY with multiple cursors and arrow keys.

Here are some easy steps you can follow to process data:

1. Download and install [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/download) , there is also a portable version available, choose whichever you like.
2. Open Sublime Text, paste ALL data on it. [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vj8K.png)
3. Observation: Each row of data has 1 and only 1 transaction, and always has 2 digits after decimal point. This is where we can start processing.
4. Highlight any `.` in a transaction with mouse cursor, and then hold `Ctrl`+`D` to until all `.` are selected.
   (Alternatively, you can press `Ctrl`+`H` to open search feature, and then click `Find All` button to select all `.`) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJJMm.png)
5. Press arrow key `->` 3 times to move to the end of every transaction, then press `Enter` key. Now you have separated every transactions in rows. [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTmJn.png)
6. Next, you need add delimiters. Follow *Step 4* to select all `$`, press arrow key `<-` move left once, and then type `#` as delimiters (or any other character that is not used in your raw data). [Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxBAI.png)
7. Same as *Step 6*, select all `/20`, move left 6 times any type "#" before dates.[Screenshot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8eDx.png)
8. Finally, you can save it as `.txt` file, and then use [Text Import Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) in feature in Excel and use `#` as delimiters to get the result you want.

These moves may seem complicated at first, but after you get familiar with it, it
only takes a few minutes and can save you a lot of time to process data like this in the future.

Comment: What about cell format?